# How to delete a record and change ids of other records accordingly?

Tags: sql, oracle, primary-key, sql-delete

Suppose I have a table like this:

```
cust_id    cust_name
=======    ========
1          monir
2          babu
3          abir
4          bro
5          debsu
```

If delete the first row, the table becomes:

```
cust_id    cust_name
=======    ========
2          babu
3          abir
4          bro
5          debsu
```

But I want the row with `cust_name = 'babu'` to have `cust_id = 1` and for the rest of the records to decrease `cust_id` by 1 automatically as I delete the first record.

That means new table should be like:

```
cust id    custname
=======    ========
1         babu
2         abir
3         bro
4         debsu
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 3):

The requirement doesn't make sense.  Changing the primary key of a row is something that you should be working very hard to avoid.  Particularly something like a `customer_id` which is likely to be in multiple child tables as well.  Updating every row in a table because one row was removed will also be terribly expensive.

That said, if you're determined, you could just

```
update customer
   set customer_id = customer_id - 1
 where customer_id > 1;
```

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - Sorry, typo, that should have been - not =.

Comment: @AbIrChanda - The requirement still doesn't make sense.  The `update` statement that I posted will do exactly what you want.  It's just not a sensible thing to do.

Comment: what if I delete the fourth record,
cust_id    cust_name
=======    ========
1          monir
2          babu
3          abir
5          debsu
the update query is not working for this one .

Comment: @AbIrChanda - Why not?  If you delete `customer_id` 4, the `where` clause for the `update` would need to change to `customer_id > 4`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're interesting in query results (as a developer), but not of exact table contents (which belongs on responsibility of DBA). So a useful practice for developers is to minimize direct interactions with DB tables - and as a simplest solution you can create a view suitable for custom requirements.

Let's modify your example, trying to avoid primary key juggling (as Justin Cave said) and put a flag column, which shows us, which users are active.

```
CREATE TABLE myTable(
  cust_id   NUMBER(10),
  cust_name VARCHAR2(1000),
  is_active CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'Y'
);

CREATE VIEW myView AS 
SELECT rownum      AS cust_effective_id
     , t.cust_name AS cust_name
     , t.cust_id   AS cust_real_id 
     -- last column just for control so you see what's happening
  FROM (SELECT *
          FROM myTable
         WHERE is_active = 'Y'
         ORDER BY cust_id) t;
```

Let's insert some records

```
INSERT INTO myTable (cust_id, cust_name)
    SELECT 1 AS cust_id, 'monir' AS cust_name FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'babu'  FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'abir'  FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'bro'   FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 5, 'debsu' FROM dual
```

Now we can see them querying `myView`

```
SELECT * FROM myView

CUST_EFFECTIVE_ID | CUST_NAME | CUST_REAL_ID
--------------------------------------------
        1         |     monir |     1
        2         |     babu  |     2
        3         |     abir  |     3
        4         |     bro   |     4
        5         |     debsu |     5
```

Now istead of delete record we mark it as inactive

```
UPDATE myTable SET is_active = 'N' WHERE cust_id = 1
```

*You may be interesting of how to do it using triggers then
[docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm#sthref1186) and [wise man](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:686424821718) will help you, but here I'm not gonna weary you with complications.*

And again let's look what we get in the view:

```
SELECT * FROM myView

CUST_EFFECTIVE_ID | CUST_NAME | CUST_REAL_ID
--------------------------------------------
        1         |     babu  |     2
        2         |     abir  |     3
        3         |     bro   |     4
        4         |     debsu |     5
```

We see that `CUST_EFFECTIVE_ID` has changed accordingly.

**Note**, that the above is just a scratch showing one of the directions: the flexibility Oracle DB gives us is almost inexhaustible and you can customize `myView` a lot of ways, and some of them can suit your purposes.